Difference of differences uniformly bounded implies equal derivatives?
I wasn't sure what to title my question -- feel free to edit it if you think of a more appropriate title.
I've convinced myself of a surprising property, and I'm wondering if it is indeed correct. Suppose I know for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$
$$\lvert \left[ f(x) - f(y) \right] - \left[ g(x) - g(y) \right] \rvert \leq \alpha$$
for some constant $\alpha \geq 0$. I claim $f'(x) = g'(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. My proof is simple.
$$\lvert \left[ f(x) - f(y) \right] - \left[ g(x) - g(y) \right] \rvert \leq \alpha \implies f(x) - f(y)\leq \alpha + g(x) - g(y)$$
Then using the definition of the derivative
$$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} \leq \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\alpha + g(x + h) - g(x)}{h} \implies f'(x) \leq g'(x)$$
Then we repeat starting from
$$\lvert \left[ f(x) - f(y) \right] - \left[ g(x) - g(y) \right] \rvert \leq \alpha \implies g(x) - g(y)\leq \alpha + f(x) - f(y)$$
to conclude $g'(x) \leq f'(x)$ and we're done.

What if $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g(x)=\cos x$?

Surely my proof can’t be right, as it would imply $f$ and $g$ are equal up to a constant which is much stronger than the original hypothesis. I’m curious where my flaw is, though

By the way, you could've also seen
$$|[f(x+h)-f(x)]-[g(x+h)-g(x)]|\le\alpha\Rightarrow|f'(x)-g'(x)|\le\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac\alpha{h}=\infty$$ yields nothing meaningful. If something holds for all $x,y\in\Bbb R$, you could've just consider $y=x+h$.

Of course, if the derivatives exist. Also, what you assumed was, given $h:=f-g$,$$|h(x)-h(y)|\le\alpha,\forall x,y\in\Bbb R$$ which, in turn, implies, for a fixed $x_0\in\Bbb R$, $$|h(x_0)-h(x)|\le\alpha,\forall x\in\Bbb R\Rightarrow h(x)\in \overline{B(x_0;\alpha)},\forall x\in\Bbb R\Rightarrow \operatorname{Im}h\in \overline{B(x_0,\alpha)},$$ so, $h$ is bounded. Bounded differentiable functions can have unbounded derivatives. Consider $h(x):=\sin(e^x)$.

From basic definitions, to fresh our minds, if $(a_n){n\in\Bbb N}\subseteq\Bbb R$ is a sequence bounded from above, then there is $a=\sup\limits{n\in\Bbb N}a_n$ and, $\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists n\in\Bbb N$ s. t. $a\le a_n+\varepsilon$. You cannot conclude there is $a_n\ge a$... which is what is addressed in the answer.

The solution is wrong. The point is that $$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} \leq \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\alpha + g(x + h) - g(x)}{h} \implies f'(x) \leq +\infty(\text{if}\ \alpha>0).$$
You can not deduce that $f'(x)\leq +\infty \implies f'(x)\leq g'(x)$.
Reason: If $g'(x)$ exist for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\vert g'(x)\vert<\infty$ and $$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\alpha + g(x + h) - g(x)}{h}$$ exist, then $$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{\alpha}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{\alpha+g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}-g'(x)$$ exists, which is a contradiction if $\alpha>0$. This is the reason why I can conclude that $$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\alpha + g(x + h) - g(x)}{h}=\infty.$$

Of course! Taking $h \to 0$ makes $\frac{\alpha}{h}$ blow up, not disappear!
